# What does 'by' mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Visitors can rest **by** the peaceful palm-shaded central
>   courtyard.

What is the usage of 'by' in this sentence?It means
''beside'' or ''showing the way of taking a rest''?

Comment: Beside. . . .  . .

Comment: As a suggestion: This kind of questions can be answered using a dictionary. You only need to check all the possible definitions of a specific word. In this case you must check the preposition BY in the dictionary.

Comment: You need to explain how each of your options fits into the meaning of your phrase, otherwise you are just asking us to choose the correct definition.

Comment: I think this is on-topic and shows basic research or knowledge. Remember that learning a language is also learning new systems of logic, often very different than L1 systems.

Comment: If a big baboon, by the light of the moon, can comb his auburn hair, why can't a learner reasonably experience the problem posed?

Comment: @Cardinal They keep telling me here that a dictionary is not a good resource for learners when it comes to parts of speech. Prepositions are especially subject to this caveat.

Comment: I think there's a balance. Ultimately, can't nearly all our questions be answered by performing research? (A balance that's often hard to strike.)

Answer (score 1):

*By* means *beside* or *near* in this usage.

Answer (score 0):

The word "by" can be a preposition or an adverb, depending on the usage and context. Here, "by" is used as a preposition, preceding a noun, which is in this context a location. Therefore, it implies that the waiting can be done "over the", or "near the palm-shaded central courtyard. "